# Remove freezes in stream record using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have original video with stream record. I need to remove freezes caused by network issues. I notice that sometimes it freezes only video, sometimes video and audio.

I tried to use command:
`ffmpeg -i original.flv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -err_detect ignore_err -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -vf 'setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB' -af 'asetpts=N/SAMPLE_RATE/TB' out.mp4`

As result freezes was removed but audio out of sync. I notice that last 3 seconds of converted video has only audio without video. Original video haven't audio sync issues

Can I remove frames where missed video and audio?

ffmpeg version 4.2.2

ffprobe of original video:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'original.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:07:37.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3810 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
```

ffprobe of converted video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:05:31.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3367 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3289 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: This can't be done. If frames were dropped or lost during recording, they can't be recovered. At best, you can reduce the duration of freezes, as you have done.

Comment: @Gyan I don't need recover lost frames. My problem is audio out-of-sync after removing freezes using command above

Comment: @gr8 Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ScottCate no, not found